# Compiling Diesel migrations on musl: undefined symbol strlcpy

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

The following is a minimal working example of Diesel's `diesel_migrations` crate failing to compile on musl through Docker using the `clux/muslrust` image. It gives an `undefined symbol: strlcpy` error. The code works fine on the native system (macOS).

### Docker command

```
docker run \
  -v cargo-cache:/root/.cargo \
  -v "$PWD:/volume" \
  --rm -it clux/muslrust cargo build --release
```

### Full cargo output

```
       Fresh bitflags v1.0.1
       Fresh unicode-xid v0.0.4
       Fresh byteorder v1.2.1
       Fresh antidote v1.0.0
       Fresh uuid v0.5.1
       Fresh num-traits v0.2.0
       Fresh itoa v0.3.4
       Fresh quote v0.3.15
       Fresh serde v1.0.27
       Fresh cfg-if v0.1.2
       Fresh dtoa v0.4.2
       Fresh synom v0.11.3
       Fresh scheduled-thread-pool v0.2.0
       Fresh num-traits v0.1.43
       Fresh log v0.4.1
       Fresh syn v0.11.11
       Fresh serde_json v1.0.9
       Fresh pq-sys v0.4.4
       Fresh r2d2 v0.8.2
       Fresh diesel_derives v1.1.0
       Fresh diesel v1.1.1
       Fresh migrations_internals v1.1.0
       Fresh migrations_macros v1.1.0
   Compiling diesel_migrations v1.1.0
     Running `rustc --crate-name diesel_migrations /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel_migrations-1.1.0/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg 'feature="default"' -C metadata=4358fb7d50fa83b4 -C extra-filename=-4358fb7d50fa83b4 --out-dir /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl -L dependency=/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps -L dependency=/volume/target/release/deps --extern migrations_internals=/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmigrations_internals-0fb7c87a53458af1.rlib --extern migrations_macros=/volume/target/release/deps/libmigrations_macros-410fd6f73c776a1c.so --cap-lints allow -L native=/musl/lib`
error: /volume/target/release/deps/libmigrations_macros-410fd6f73c776a1c.so: undefined symbol: strlcpy
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel_migrations-1.1.0/src/lib.rs:77:1
   |
77 | extern crate migrations_macros;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: Could not compile `diesel_migrations`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name diesel_migrations /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel_migrations-1.1.0/src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg feature="default" -C metadata=4358fb7d50fa83b4 -C extra-filename=-4358fb7d50fa83b4 --out-dir /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl -L dependency=/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps -L dependency=/volume/target/release/deps --extern migrations_internals=/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmigrations_internals-0fb7c87a53458af1.rlib --extern migrations_macros=/volume/target/release/deps/libmigrations_macros-410fd6f73c776a1c.so --cap-lints allow -L native=/musl/lib` (exit code: 101)
```

### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "diesel_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John Doe <example@email.com>"]

[dependencies]
diesel_migrations = "1"

[dependencies.diesel]
version = "1"
features = ["postgres", "uuid", "serde_json", "r2d2", "large-tables"]
```

### src/main.rs

```
#[macro_use] extern crate diesel_migrations;
extern crate diesel;

embed_migrations!();

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

### migrations/2018-02-07-164146_create_post/up.sql

```sql
-- Your SQL goes here
create table posts (
    id serial primary key,
)
```

### migrations/2018-02-07-164146_create_post/down.sql

```sql
-- Your SQL goes here
drop table posts
```

Comment: Perhaps related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43486

Comment: In your SQL, I would recommend putting semi-colons at the end of the statements.